# How to enable dead code warnings in Haskell (GHC)

Tags: haskell, ghc

Some languages (like Go & Rust) require the programmer to be diligent in removing all dead code from the source. This has benefits in code maintainability and readability, if a bit extreme for some users.

How can I enable this feature in Haskell? (Is it possible?) For example, in the following code, I'd like `url2` to be flagged as dead code because it isn't used in `main`.

```
url1 = "http://stackoverflow.com"
url2 = "http://stackexchange.com"

main = print url1
```

I saw reference to some compiler flags (e.g. `-fwarn-unused-binds`, `-fwarn-name-shadowing`, and `-fwarn-hi-shadowing`) but none of them seem to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Does anything show up with `-Wall` about unused names when you compile that code?  If not, then GHC does not warn against it.

Comment: No. That forces type signatures to be added, but not dead code warnings.

Comment: Then I don't believe that GHC will check that.  See [the GHC docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html) for what warnings are available.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

GHC will report `url2` as dead code with `-fwarn-unused-binds` if you restrict the list of exports from the module appropriately, e.g.:

```
module Main(main) where
...
```

If your module header is just

```
module Main where
```

then you are implicitly exporting everything and so it can't consider any top-level binding to be unused.

Comment: Great. Is there a way to require a `module` line in the source file too?

Comment: The default if `module` isn't specified is `module Main(main) where` - see https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-990005.1, but I'm not aware of any warning that allows you to insist that it the `module` line is provided.